# Get my public IP using netcat

Tags: ip, public, netcat

I have a very basic Linux server running on an IP camera (Busybox). I'd like to get the public IP of that camera, which is located behind a router.
It has no "wget" nor "traceroute", and "ping" is just answering "alive" or "not alive"...

The only one available is a basic "netcat" :

```
nc
BusyBox v1.1.3 (2009.12.07-16:16+0000) multi-call binary
Usage: nc [OPTIONS] [IP] [port]
Netcat opens a pipe to IP:port
Options:
        -l              listen mode, for inbound connects
        -p PORT         local port number
        -i SECS         delay interval for lines sent
        -w SECS         timeout for connects and final net reads
        -4              Use IPv4 (default)
        -6              Use IPv6
        -D DSCP         set IP DSCP field
        -P PRIO         set VLAN user-priority
```

Provided my ISP allows outgoing HTTP, is it possible to use netcat in order to get the public IP response from a site like www.obtainip.com or similar ?

GREAT and many thanks to both of you guys as I did not feel comfortable with nc at all.

Here are the 2 working ways :

```
echo "GET /automation/n09230945.asp HTTP/1.0" > http_req2.txt
echo "Host: www.whatismyip.com" >> http_req2.txt
echo "" >> http_req2.txt
echo "" >> http_req2.txt
IP2=$(cat http_req2.txt | nc www.whatismyip.com 80 | tail -n 1)
echo $IP2
YEAH !
```

and more strange but... it also works :

```
echo "GET / HTTP/1.0" > http_request.txt
echo "Host: www.whatismyip.com" >> http_request.txt
echo "User-Agent: netcat" >> http_request.txt
echo "Referer: http://www.whatismyip.com/" >> http_request.txt
echo "" >> http_request.txt
echo "" >> http_request.txt
IP=$(cat http_request.txt | nc www.whatismyipaddress.com 80 | tail -n 1)
echo $IP
YEAH again!
```

EDIT
Of course, this can be scripted better like suggested :

```
echo -e "GET /automation/n09230945.asp HTTP/1.0\n"Host: www.whatismyip.com\n\n" | nc www.whatismyipaddress.com 80 | tail -n 1
```

Comment: hum I can't install wget or curl otherwise I'd have loved doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a file called 'script'

put this in the contents

```
GET /automation/n09230945.asp HTTP/1.0
Host: www.whatismyip.com
```

Make sure there are 2 empty linefeeds on the bottom (this editor wont show them)

then run

```
cat script | nc www.whatismyip.com 80 | tail -1
```

There is your ip... you can put it in a variable like

```
IP=`cat script | nc www.whatismyip.com 80 | tail -1`
echo $IP
```

This will return just the ip address, no fuss

Comment: This isn't working for me. I created the `script` file with the appropriate content (including two empty lines at the bottom). But `cat script | nc www.whatismyip.com 80 | tail -1` prints nothing. If I simplify it to `cat script | nc www.whatismyip.com 80`, it still prints nothing.

Comment: whatismyip's automation is down, use this instead: `nc icanhazip.com 80`, then `GET /`.

Answer (score 4):

Since whatismyip.com's automation is down, here's an alternative:

```
$ echo GET / | nc icanhazip.com 80
```

...which will output your IP.

Comment: Cool. This could be one-liner `echo GET /|nc icanhazip.com 80`

Comment: Updated to just use curl.

Comment: The question is how to get external IP with usage of **netcat**, not curl.

Comment: Hah, that's what I get for updating an answer after 2 years without reading the question. Updated to use your simplified version @avalanchy

Answer (score 2):

You **can** use netcat to send a working, canned HTTP request:

**command**

```
cat httpreq.txt | nc www.whatismyip.com 80
```

**httpreq.txt** (make sure to end the file with at least two blank lines)

```
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.whatismyip.com
User-Agent: netcat
Referer: http://www.whatismyip.com/


<<don't forget your blank lines above here>>
```

...**but** you will still need some mechanism to parse the HTTP response.

Even if you can find a "what is my IP" web service that returns only the unadorned IP address in plain text (freeing you from having to parse HTML), you will still need to parse off the HTTP response headers.

What facilities do you have that might allow you to do some string parsing?  BASH?  sed?  awk?

Edit: looks like [superfro found a plain-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253237/get-my-public-ip-with-netcat/4253324#4253324) "what is my ip" service, and an easy way to parse off the HTTP response headers.

Comment: yes I have tail, sed and grep available but no awk. I can also bash scripting using telnet.

Amazing as I get an error 500 using it straight as it is, but I get the public IP, keeping the httpreq.text with nc to www.whatismyipaddress.com, just like this :

cat http_request.txt
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: www.whatismyip.com
User-Agent: netcat
Referer: http://www.whatismyip.com/
IP=$(cat http_request.txt | nc www.whatismyipaddress.com 80 | tail -n 1)

Comment: Take a look at superfro's solution.  Since you have tail. :-)

Comment: I think I'll rather keep yours as it looks more generic and I'm afraid that this "GET /automation/n09230945.asp" disappears some days.

Comment: @hornetbzz - I don't think there's any reason to be afraid of the `/automation/n09230945.asp` URL.  It is mentioned several times on that website's forum as an alternate way to retrieve your IP address.  Using it will making parsing the IP address much easier.  But, use what you like, and what works for you!

Comment: thx, in fact, I'll script both in the shell then I'm twice sure to get this IP and later avoiding wondering why I don't get it ;-) Many Thx again as actually each of you both really helped me efficiently and kindly.

Answer (score 1):

```
(echo GET /; echo) |nc www.whatismyipaddress.com 80 | grep -o "[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}"
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have sed on your box, you can try

```
echo -e "GET /automation/n09230945.asp HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.whatismyip.com\r\n" | nc -w1 www.whatismyip.com 80 | sed -ne '$p'
```

Comment: IP=$(echo -e "GET /automation/n09230945.asp HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.whatismyip.com\r\n" | nc -w1 www.whatismyip.com 80 | tail -1)